# Ubuntu users management, groups, users, permissions

Tags: permissions, ssh, apache2, home-directory

My original problem is that I want to create a shared hosting like environment on my VPS. Basically, what I want is to have multiple directories within my apache web-root, which will all be designated to a particular website, which should be wrx accessible by multiple users. Along with that, I'm trying to have files created and changed by ssh/sftp users be accessible to other users I assign that particular website to. So, a use-case, assuming www-data is Apache user and www-data is Apache group:

I want to have, say, 2 websites, www.foo.com and www.bar.com. Path to their publicly visible directories are, respectively:

- /var/www/html/www.foo.com/www
- /var/www/html/www.bar.com/www

  I also want to have 3 users, Bob, Mark and Layla, that can SSH/SFTP into the VPS, following these rules:
- Bob can SFTP/SSH into VPS, and his landing directory should be /var/www/html/www.foo.com. Bob should be able to read, execute and write to every single directory and file within landing dir. Apache should too.
- Mark and Layla can SFTP/SSH into VPS, and landing directory for both of them shoud be /var/www/html/www.bar.com. Apache should too.

I've tried to make this happen, by adding users, changing their home directories, putting them in various groups, but there was always an issue when I tried to log-in as those. /var/log/auth.log wasn't really helpful, except for mentioning chroot. Now, I've read about jailkit, but am still unsure on both how to set it up to have what I want nor would it help. Any help would be much appreciated.